# Repair Flash Disk

Tags: usb-flash-drive, repair, format, filesystems

i have a flash disk, which i somehow ****ed doing some formatings and all... now it doesnot work...

- it is loaded but i cannot copy any files to it and inside there is a large 3.85 GB file with no extension and it cannot be delete when i do so it says cannot read the source disk
- and when i try to copy anything to the disk it say the disk is write protected
- when i try to format\quick format the disk it fails...

i think that there is no file system in the disk.. what to do is there any way or tool to repair it...

one method is plugin the flash disk, insert the windows disk, restart, go to repair and format the flash disk.. BUT i am avoiding that is there another way

Comment: If you can't even format it, you have a hardware or OS problem. What operating system and tool did you use to format, and error message do you get when you try to format?

Comment: Xp and theres is no tool i used and when i try to format\quick format the disk it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `chkdsk [volume] /r` from the command prompt to see if its able to fix any of the filesystem errors and bring it back to a usable state.